Запуск программы с указанием IP адреса Debian
Ситуация следующая.Есть программа, она использует IP адрес компьютера. Компьютеру заданы 2 IP адреса. Есть ли возможность запустить программу что бы ей был виден только конкретный адрес? А именно что бы одна копия программы была на адресе 192.xxx.xxx.1 другая на 192.xxx.xxx.2.
Предвещая вопросы.Нет, программа не может настраиваться, и садится на все доступные в системе адреса автоматом

Если запускать программы в LXC-контейнерах, то можно. Возможно можно с помощью namespaces см. netns - не помню уже.
